# Enable disable Selectric select box

Tags: javascript, jquery

I applyed to my select boxes the elegant [Selectric JQuery plugin](http://lcdsantos.github.io/jQuery-Selectric/), but now I'm not able to enable or disable a certain select box by checking or unchecking a checkbox. I noticed that **if I remove the pluging, the following code works fine. If the plugin is loaded, the code doesn't work**.

```
<div class="labels-chk">
    <input type="checkbox" id="chk2" class="css-checkbox" name="Message">
    <label for="chk2" class="css-label">Show notification message&nbsp;</label>
</div>

<select id="select-warnings" disabled>
    <option value="load">as soon as page has loaded</option>
    <option value="date">on date</option>
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $('select').selectric();

        $("#chk2").click(function() {
            var checked_status = this.checked;
            if (checked_status == true) {
                $("#select-warnings").removeAttr("disabled");
            } else {
                $("#select-warnings").attr("disabled", "disabled");
            }
        });
     });
</script>
```

Comment: use .prop instead of your removeAttr or attr. https://api.jquery.com/prop/

Comment: but the selectric plugin makes you a nice looking selectbox and is made with normal tags. i have made such things on my own. less problems

Comment: maybe reinitialize selectric

Comment: here you go: $('#mySelectList').prop('selectedIndex', 0).selectric('refresh');

Comment: Thank you bradelizer. I work it out exactly in the same minutes you answered me!

Answer (score 7):

Ok, I got it! Selectric has to be **refreshed**.

Change:

```
$("#select-warnings").removeAttr("disabled");
```

and

```
$("#select-warnings").attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

To:

```
$("#select-warnings").removeAttr("disabled").selectric('refresh');
```

and

```
$("#select-warnings").attr("disabled", "disabled").selectric('refresh');
```

Comment: please use prop('disabled',true) or prop('disabled',false) instead attr. I had many issues because of attr

Answer (score 2):

After altering the select state you have to use selectric `refresh` method.

Code:

```
$('#dynamic').selectric();

$('#toggleDis').click(function (e) {
        if ($("#toggleDis").hasClass("disabled")) {
    $('#dynamic').prop('disabled', false);
}
else {
    $('#dynamic').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
}
    $(this).toggleClass('disabled');
    var Selectric = $('select').data('selectric');
    Selectric.refresh(); // Reconstruct the plugin options box
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/vcLz2seu/

Answer (score 2):

To disable already applied selectric use

```
$('select').selectric('destroy');
```

Comment: This is what solved it for me. On the specific select ID component. Then I re-enabled selectric again: $('select').selectric();